# Vertx 3 application logging from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, vert.x

Sometimes it's nice to log things to the console during development.  In a Vert.x 3 project I'm creating, I'm trying to follow the instructions on the docs page for Vert.x 3 for logging:

http://vert-x3.github.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_logging_from_your_application

The docs provide this sample code:

```
// Note -these classes are Java only

// You would normally maintain one static instance of Logger per Java class:

var logger = Java.type("io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory").getLogger(className);

logger.info("something happened");
logger.error("oops!", exception);
```

When compiling, the "var logger = ..." line bombs out with this error:

> Failed in deploying verticle  java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:391)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$13$1895AAAAA$\^eval_.L:27$_load(null:107)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$4$4036AAAA$\^eval_.L:27$doRequire(null:149)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:644)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:229)

(Note: that "className" variable looks suspicious too.  It doesn't say anywhere what that's supposed to be, it's "undefined" at compile time at the moment)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious - if you use javascript anyway, why not node.js?

Comment: I have succumbed to it's many charms: http://vert-x3.github.io   Plus the big boss says it's happening because scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to versions getting slightly out of sync in the Vertx 3 milestones. The documentation already reflects a change upcoming in milestone 7 where the class package is:

```
    io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory
```

However, in milestone 6 you need to use:

```
    io.vertx.core.logging.impl.LoggerFactory
```

If you update your code to:

```
    var logger = Java.type("io.vertx.core.logging.impl.LoggerFactory").getLogger(className);
```

it should work.